# IERC20.approve(spender, amount) thinks the owner is also the contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, erc-20-approve

I have these functions and deployed my contract to Ropsten testnet.

```
  function setSmartContractAllownace(uint daiAmountIn) public {
     IERC20 daiToken = IERC20(ropstenDAI);
     daiToken.approve(address(this), daiAmountIn);
  }

  function getContractAddress() public view returns (address) {
      return address(this);
  }
  
  function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
      return msg.sender;
  }
```

When I call `getContractAddress()` and `getOwner()`, they return the correct values respectively.

However, when I call `setSmartContractAllownace(1000)`, it successfully approves, but the caller (owner) is set to the **address of the smart contract**.

I verified this by going into DAI and checking the allowance.

This is when I put my account with DAI as `_owner` and smart contract as `_spender`

[image]

As you can see, this returns 0.

But if I put `_owner` also as smart contract,

[image]

it shows the correct allowance.

What is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: well approve allow you the spender to spend the amount of the transaction sender. So the owner is right because the contract send the transaction not you.

Comment: How do you allow my contract to take Tokens from my account then?

Comment: Doing `someToken.approve(address(this), someAmount)` is **meaningless**, as you are only approving the contract to transfer tokens **from itself** (i.e., you can now call `transferFrom` inside this contract, but heck, you may as well just call `transfer` without any approval, and get the exact same result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had a misunderstanding about Tokens already publishes vs Token contract I was writing.

**I ended up not using REMIX and my own smart contracts.**

I used **Web3js** and loaded publishes DAI contract via this code

```
let token = new web3.eth.Contract(erc20ABI.abi, daiContractAddress)
token.methods.approve(uniswapRouter02Address, tokenAmountIn)
    .send({ from: web3.eth.defaultAccount, gas: gasLimit })
    ... // some listeners
```

Using the same approach, I was able to load other contracts I needed and use them.

The problems I didn't understand, or still don't know are

1. I cannot approve tokens already published through REMIX
2. If I call `approve` from a contract, the contract approves the fund to be used for the spender
3. Those YouTube videos about writing contract for ERC20 tokens are MY OWN tokens, so I shouldn't do that if I'm not planning on publishing my own tokens.

Thank you for being patient and helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `IERC20.approve()` function's [signature](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol), you can see, that the first argument is the address that you allow to spend your DAI.

You used `daiToken.approve(address(this), daiAmountIn)` which means you allowed your contract to spend the DAI of your contract. This makes not much sense.

If you simply want to add some token to your contract from your own funds, you can transfer with your wallet to your contract's address. In this case just send some DAI to the contract's address.

If you would like to spend the caller's DAI tokens, then you have to allow it first. But of course the contract can't allow itself to spend others funds. You can go to etherscan to the DAI token's  contract and call the `approve()` here with your contract's address. After that you will be able to call `transferFrom()` from your contract successfully up to the allowed amount.

Comment: My goal is to call `daiToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), daiAmountIn)` so I can transfer some tokens to my contract. If I call `daiToken.approve(msg.sender, daiAmmountIn)`, it doesn't make sense to "transfer from msg.sender to contract", because I'm approved to do the opposite way.

Comment: my account in my wallet, which owns the contract

Comment: Editet my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** DON'T EVER USE DELEGATECALL IN PRODUCTION. IT IS VERY DANGEROUS IF YOU DON'T KNOW HOW TO USE IT.

You need to use delegate call if you want the target contract to know that the caller is you.

> DelegateCall, as the name implies, is calling mechanism of how caller
> contract calls target contract function but when target contract
> executed its logic, the context is not on the user who execute caller
> contract but on caller contract

In you case, it should be something like this:
`address(ropsten).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address,uint256)", address(this), value))`

further reading: https://medium.com/coinmonks/delegatecall-calling-another-contract-function-in-solidity-b579f804178c